# A bug about Unmarshal yaml into struct

Tags: go, yaml, prometheus

I want to unmarshal a []byte variable int struct prometheusyml. Here are the definition of promethuesyml and []byte variable.

```
type prometheusyml struct {
        Global        global          `yaml:"global,omitempty"`
        ScrapeConfigs []scrapeConfigs `yaml:"scrape_configs,omitempty"`
}

type global struct {
        ScrapeInterval     string `yaml:"scrape_interval,omitempty"`
        EvaluationInterval string `yaml:"evaluation_interval,omitempty"`
}

type scrapeConfigs struct {
        JobNmaes        string            `yaml:"job_name,omitempty"`
        RelabelConfigs  []relabelConfigs  `yaml:"relabel_configs,omitempty"`
        MetricsPath     string            `yaml:"metrics_path,omitempty"`
        Scheme          string            `yaml:"scheme,omitempty"`
        ConsulSdConfigs []consulSdConfigs `yaml:"consul_sd_configs,omitempty"`
}

type relabelConfigs struct {
        SourceLabels string `yaml:"source_labels,omitempty"`
        Action       string `yaml:"action,omitempty"`
        Regex        string `yaml:"regex,omitempty"`
        Replacement  string `yaml:"replacement,omitempty"`
        TargetLabel  string `yaml:"target_label,omitempty"`
}

type consulSdConfigs struct {
        Server   string   `yaml:"server,omitempty"`
        Services []string `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).


scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'consul'
    relabel_configs:
        - source_labels:  ["__meta_consul_service"]
          action: replace
          regex: "(.*)"
          replacement: '${1}'
          target_label: "service"
        - source_labels: ["__meta_consul_tags"]
          action: replace
          regex: ',(?:[^,]+,){0}([^=]+)=([^,]+),.*'
          replacement: '${2}'
          target_label: '${1}'
        - source_labels: ["__meta_consul_tags"]
          action: replace
          regex: ',(?:[^,]+,){1}([^=]+)=([^,]+),.*'
          replacement: '${2}'
          target_label: '${1}'
        - source_labels: ["__meta_consul_tags"]
          action: replace
          regex: ',(?:[^,]+,){2}([^=]+)=([^,]+),.*'
          replacement: '${2}'
          target_label: '${1}'
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: http
    consul_sd_configs:
        - server: 192.168.0.101:8500
          services:
              - cfs
```

But when I ran the program. It shows the error which implies that source_labels can't be unmarshaled into struct. It's likely that ["__meta_consul_tags"] can't be translated into string!!!! But what should I do to fix the bug? And what's the actural type?

```
line 11: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string
```

Comment: You declare the field supposed to be filled with `SourceLabels` as a `string`, but you try to pass it `["__meta_consul_service"]`. Since the name is plural, do you not mean to take in _a slice of strings_? That could be achieved by changing the line to `SourceLabels []string \`yaml:"source_labels,omitempty"\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source_labels` in `relabel_configs` is clearly an array of `string`. So, you have to replace `data type` of `SourceLabels` from `string` to `[]string`. Then you are good to go.

```golang
type relabelConfigs struct {
    SourceLabels []string `yaml:"source_labels,omitempty"`
    Action       string   `yaml:"action,omitempty"`
    Regex        string   `yaml:"regex,omitempty"`
    Replacement  string   `yaml:"replacement,omitempty"`
    TargetLabel  string   `yaml:"target_label,omitempty"`
}
```

Simply just changing this solves your problem.